# Nest.Js Redirect from a controller to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

So I have this module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController, AnotherController],
  providers: [],
})
```

And in `AppController` on some route I want to do `res.redirect('/books')` where `/books` is a route found in `AnotherController`.

For some reason this doesn't work and I can't figure out if it's not supported or I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Redirecting from one controller to another works with `res.redirect(target)`. As target, you have to combine the paths from the controller and the route annotation:

`@Controller('books')` + `@Get('greet')` = `/books/greet`

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  redirect(@Res() res) {
    return res.redirect('/books/greet');
  }
}

@Controller('books')
export class AnotherController {
  @Get('greet')
  greet() {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

---

See this running example here:

[image: Edit Redirect-Controller]

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. What is weird is that I keep my controllers in 2 separate files and it doesn't work like that. It only works if i don't specify anything in the `@Controller()` and then write `@Get('/books/greet')`. Which is weird because this is something that I understand is by default.

Comment: Apparently having another route like `/books/:id` written as `@Get(':id')` was breaking it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do that is to use the @Redirect() decorator as documented here:
https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection

This should work as well:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  @Redirect('books')
  redirect(){}
}

@Controller('books')
export class AnotherController {
  @Get()
  getBooks() {
    return 'books';
  }
}
```

Comment: note, this only works with `GET` method, any url provided with otherwise will be sent with a get first causing the endpoint not to be found